# How to setup subdomain on Apache2 server so that is uses the same SSL as main domain?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I am trying to add a subdomain called "privacy" on my Apache2 server, using Ubuntu that uses the same SSL as the main domain.

I have created the directory "privacy" in the "www" directory as well as correctly pointed the DNS.

How to configure in the simplest way possible the subdomain so that it uses the same ssl as the main domain?

Here are my current files structure and file content:

```
root@example:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1586 Mar 23 22:04 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6338 Feb 23  2021 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1726 Mar 23 21:39 example.com-ssl.conf
```

This is the "000-default.conf":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the "default-ssl.conf":

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is the "example.com-ssl.conf":

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html      
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com.ca-bundle
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: To have another name with the same settings simple extend the ServerAlias with the new domain, i.e. add privacy.example.com to the same place where you already have www.example.com. Or for a new document root add a new VirtualHost with a different ServerName and ServerAlias which uses the same  SSL* settings. But of course you need to be sure that the existing certificate actually covers the new subdomain, because otherwise you get certificate errors. But what domains are covered by the existing certificate has nothing to do with Apache configuration.